# Incorrect number of count

Tags: sql

I am having a problem regarding my query. I'll use an example instead. So, for the disease name called 'Abscess', this has been diagnosed twice in my diagnosed table, yet I only get a count of 1. However when I check it by using the diseaseid in my diagnosed table, I get 2. Please reconstruct my answer below!

Question:
List all disease names and a count of how many times each disease has been diagnosed at
the clinic. The list is of rarely identified diseases, so show only diseases that have a
diagnosis count of less than 5. Note: Zero is less than 5. Provide the SQL query and a data
VISUALISATION of the results.

[image: mysql(lookatabscess)]

[image: Diagnosedrecord]

My answer:

```
SELECT disease.name, COUNT(*) AS number_of_disease_diagnosed
FROM disease
WHERE diseaseid IN (SELECT DISTINCT diseaseid FROM diagnosed)
GROUP BY disease.name
HAVING COUNT(*) <= 5
UNION
SELECT diseaseid,0
FROM disease
WHERE diseaseid NOT IN (SELECT DISTINCT diseaseid FROM diagnosed);
```

Comment: How about giving us the schema, so that we can see the cardinality of your linking across tables?  Is `disease.name` a key to `disease`?  If so, why would you expect more than 1 `disease.name` per row in `disease`?

Comment: Your query has a number of problems.  Please show us a minimal sample of data for the `disease` and `diagnosed` tables.  Why did you undo the @Strawberry edit?

Comment: added more information guys

Comment: First, you may need `inner join` instead of `in`. Second, you should specific which RDBMS you are using, but not tag them all.

Comment: Don't tag unrelated products. I removed those tags, feel free to put one of them back, for the dbms you are using.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is with your query. As Prisoner hinted, you should use a join rather than using in subqueries.

Specifically I would use an Outer Join for this query such as:

```sql
select disease.name, count(diagnosed.diagnosedid) as Count
from
  disease
  left outer join diagnosed on disease.diseaseID = diagnosed.diseaseID
group by
  disease.Name
having
  count(diagnosed.diagnosedid) <= 5
```

The outer join will get you every single row for disease, and matching rows (where they exist) from the diagnosed table. Then the use of the GROUP BY & HAVING clauses will filter down to the results you seek.

Hope this helps.